# Why is $\left\| {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {{A_i}} } \right\|_2^2 \ge \sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left\| {{A_i}} \right\|_2^2} $ True?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_1,A_2,....A_n\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be positive semidefinite.

Why is $\left\| {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {{A_i}} } \right\|_2^2 \ge \sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left\| {{A_i}} \right\|_2^2} $ True?

Comment: Why don't you choose two $2 \times 2$ matrices that are positive semi definite and see if the inequality holds? That might help you develop an intuition for why this is true.

Comment: Isn't your inequality reversed ?

Comment: Is $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ the operator norm induced by the $\ell^2$-norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$ or the Hilbert-Schmidt norm?

Comment: @MaoWao - Hilbert-Schmidt norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hilbert-Schmidt norm is induced by the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(B^\ast A)$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Thus, sesquilinearity yields
$$\left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^m A_i\right\rVert^2_2=\sum_{i=1}^m\lVert A_i\rVert^2_2+\sum_{i\neq j}\mathrm{tr}(A_i A_j)$$
(the adjoint can be ommitted since the $A_i$ are positive semidefinite).

Now, cyclicity of the trace implies $\mathrm{tr}(A_i A_j)=\mathrm{tr}(A_i^{\frac 1 2}A_j A_i^{\frac 1 2})\geq 0$ since $A_i^{\frac 1 2}A_jA_i^{\frac 1 2}$ is positive semidefinite.

Hence we obtain
$$\left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^m A_i\right\rVert^2_2 \geq\sum_{i=1}^m\lVert A_i\rVert^2_2.$$